# Resource for understanding view, projection, 'virtual camera' in OpenGL or graphics in general

Tags: opengl, graphics, projection, opengl-3

I noticed most resources either assume you know a lot already or assume you know math of professional level or assume you're going to find other resources to fill gaps.

Is there a resource that takes someone without already a knowledge on view matrices in graphics and takes them to understanding fully how

- to set up a 'virtual camera'
- move objects
- move the observer
- etc.

If it's on OpenGL, it'd be ideal.

Notice I'm not interested in automatic ways in OpenGL since

1. They are deprecated and removed in latest versions of the spec, one has to set them manually
2. That is not understanding.

Comment: Voting to close as resource rec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Chapter 3 of the red book: http://fly.cc.fer.hr/~unreal/theredbook/